# signin and signup error

Tags: php, post

im trying to build a signin and signup system,and when im reciving the input in the php it returns this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\friend\register.php on line 5

this is the html:

```
<form id="form" class="" method="post" action="register.php">
                    <?php
                    session_start();
                    $flager = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
                    $_SESSION['formFlager3'] = $flager;
                    ?>
                    <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="<?= $_SESSION['formFlager3'] ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Name</label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control requiredField" name="name" id="name"  placeholder="Enter your Name" data-error-empty="Insert Name"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Email</label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control requiredField" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Enter your Email" data-error-empty="Insert Email"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control requiredField" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Enter your Password" data-error-empty="Insert Password" data-error-invalid="Insert a Valid Password"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirm" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control requiredField" name="confirm" id="confirm"  placeholder="Confirm your Password" data-error-empty="Confirm Password" data-error-invalid="Insert a Valid Confirm Password" data-error-match="Password Most be Matcing"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Signup" class="form-control btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">
                        <a id="create" href="index.php">Already have an account?</a>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

this is the php:

```
    session_start();
    require 'host.php';
    $link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PWD, MYSQL_DB);
​    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = ​mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $pass = ​ mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $confirm = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['confirm']);
    $echo $name . '|' . $email . '|' . $pass . '|' . $confirm;
```

Comment: Your PHP code appears to contain some unprintable characters that are messing things up. I haven't figured out what they are.

Comment: Find the section in the duplicate reference question titled "Invisible stray unicode characters".